# Second guessing my closure of this question

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

Background: 
A user posts a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811519/populating-a-count-matrix-with-permutations-of-r-data-table-rows) in the R tag. A few minutes later, the user posts the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811619/populating-a-count-matrix-with-combinations-of-pandas-dataframe-rows), but this time asks it under the pandas tag.

I noticed the connection, and pointed this out. The user's reasoning was that the problem would likely be very hard to solve using R, because the data structures best suited to the problem (tuples) were not available in that language. Which seemed reasonable to me.

So I answered the pandas question, and then closed the R question as a duplicate of the pandas question because, to me, it seemed the rational thing to do.

1. The question was an *exact* duplicate, just in a different language.
2. It seemed that the question would be more easily solved with pandas, so anyone looking for the solution to that question could be redirected to the Pandas version to see how it was solved there.

Another motivating reason for the closure is that the problem had already been solved in one language, so did we really need separate versions existing just because the language tag was different?

Now, I'm second guessing myself as to whether these reasons were good enough to warrant closure, because of a comment someone left under the R post. Perhaps it would have been better just to leave a "relevant" link in a comment and be done with it?

Would like some advice as to what the best thing to do in this situation would've been.

Comment: Separately, there are two other issues with this: 1) Nowhere did you explain why you *need* an 8x8 matrix instead of list-of-tuples (or possibly faster, an mx2 array). What do you actually use the 8x8 matrix for later on? Really you should tell us. 2) hardcoding answers to the 8x8 case is not representative and feels toy, do you care about scalability to NxN?

Comment: @smci your comment seems not to be related to this meta question. Maybe you wanted to comment on the linked SO question?

Comment: You have a fact wrong in your account of what happened here. The two questions you've linked to were *not* asked by the same user (unless one of the accounts is a sockpuppet).

Comment: The strikingly similarity between the questions may look like plagiarism... The OP should write the question themself to avoid that.

Comment: @MarkAmery sure, that's what it looks like from first glance. But based on some now deleted comments, those were obvious sockpuppets.

Comment: @coldspeed not necessarily sockpuppets. Having 2 accounts is tolerated (you can even ask for account merging), until you start voting from one account for posts of the other account...

Comment: @jps: it is related to this meta question. I'm saying  this meta discussion is moot since the original question was not a very reusable resource anyway (hardcoded to 8x8), and may be an XY question (nowhere explains why the subsequent code needs an 8x8 matrix instead of list-of-tuples/array). *"Another motivating reason for closure... had already been solved in one language"* but similarly, how scalable is ~N^2 self-joins on an NxN matrix, for large N?

Comment: @smci ok, but it sounds like you're addressing the OP of the original question, which is another person than the OP of this meta question. That's why I asked.

Comment: @jps: Oh right, my mistake. s/you/the OP/g;

Comment: I know nothing about R or Pandas, but from what you described it seems like the solution implemented in Pandas can not be implemented in R - and therefor, even if the question is the otherwise same, the answers to the two different languages would be different - Therefor, this is not a duplicate at all.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't think that a duplicate question in a different language is a duplicate at all. A user searching for how to work with strings in C# is not going to look for C++ answers. Perhaps a C++ answer would answer a subset of string-related questions, but not many of them. I certainly wouldn't seek them out directly.

The fact that it came from the same user is a bit irrelevant. Would you have closed this question in the same way if it came from a different user? I find myself asking that before I perform any moderating action on the site. If the answer is ever "no" then I've taken the personal stance that it isn't appropriate. YMMV.

@psubsee2003's answer highlights that unregistered users do not see the original question. This brings forth a very interesting idea: If the original question is required for context in order to answer a given question - then that question can't be duplicate.

Ah well.

Comment: Note that questions in all languages may be closed as duplicate of [tag:language-agnostic].

Comment: @user202729 in which case, the language isn't at all relevant to the question, isn't it?

Comment: @user202729 while a good point, I'd still exercise that with caution. Very few problems are completely language agnostic, especially to one who is still learning the differences in syntax between different languages. Dutch and German have similarities - but learning Dutch with a German textbook is probably not going to help you at all for your next holiday :P

Comment: I'd like to emphasize Shadow's caution about using language agnostic as a dupe target. Even in cases where I'm primarily looking for an algorithm to solve a problem effectively not details of how to implement an algorithm I've already selected an example in the language I'm using is almost always preferable. C/C++/C#/Java/Javascript are similar enough that 99% of the time a solution in one can be mechanically translated to any of the others and with an occasional syntax check I can process input from php/python/ruby/etc if I need to, an implementation in my target language is still preferable.

Answer (score 30):

When closing questions as duplicates the first thing to remember is unregistered users do not see the original question and they are only shown the duplicate question (unless the original question has an answer).

So when you close a question in tag [X] as a duplicate of a question in tag [Y], users who are looking for a tag [X] question answer are going to be disappointed.  Unless the answers in the other language are going to be obvious to users of all languages than closing questions in other languages as duplicate just because they are the same, you may not be helping anyone.

I get the impulse to "punish" the OP for asking a stupid duplicate question, but every time you do it when it doesn't make perfect sense, **you punish every user who finds the question in the future.**

Comment: Is important to establish who is the main beneficiary of closing as duplicate: the future reader. OP could also be considered a future reader, which is why is beneficial for them to close questions as duplicates.

Comment: Nobody's "punishing" anybody.

Comment: this answer has a point. Using "punishing" isn't that suitable. I would have said "you prevent every user from finding the question"

Comment: @GeorgeJempty in this specific case, you are correct, but in a more general sense (which I always try to cover in my meta answers), duplicate closures is definitely used as "punishment" at times and I wanted to be clear on that poiny.

Answer (score 17):

This seems like a really obviously bad closure to me. I can imagine (unusual) circumstances where closing a question against a cross-language duplicate would be reasonable, but this isn't one of them.

> It seemed that the question would be more easily solved with pandas, so anyone looking for the solution to that question could be redirected to the Pandas version to see how it was solved there.

And then what? How do they use that information?

Honestly, it's unclear to me what benefit a reader of the R question is meant to get from a cross-language duplicate at all. Are you expecting users who need to solve this problem in an R program to spin off a subprocess to run a Python script that performs the computation, then somehow parse the result (e.g. from STDOUT)? Or to rewrite their entire program in Python? Both of these seem like horrible solutions (even *if* the reader knows some Python and isn't constrained to working on a system that they cannot install Python on). But I don't see what else they're meant to do with a Python solution.

Duplicate closure wasn't warranted here at all, as far as I can see.

Comment: sometimes C++ questions asking pure OS/Clib functions can be closed with C dupes. But not the case here.