# Why is this question a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I have a lot of Git aliases which means that sometimes I forget the underlying command.

I was working on a system without my aliases, and couldn't remember how to create a new local branch and then `HEAD` to it.

I asked Stack Overflow. I was surprised that there was no question on this, so I created one and answered it, [which is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/336223)):

[Create and work on a new branch based on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46706821/create-and-work-on-a-new-branch-based-on-the-current-branch)

Two supposed duplicates were flagged. I differentiated the question from those, and asked for the question to be reopened.

Two new supposed duplicates were flagged. I differentiated the question from these as well, and asked that the question be reopened.

It wasn't, and no comments were given.

I believe this question would be very useful to beginners at `git`, (and for people who forget the commands underlying their aliases!)

Perhaps I'm missing something about what constitutes a duplicate question. Could someone please explain which of the supposed duplicates they believe to be a duplicate and why?

---

**Update:**

The question has now been deleted. I've asked a meta-meta-question here:

[Why was this question under discussion on meta.SO deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373579/5353461)

Comment: Part of the problem is that you don't ask "How do I create a branch and work on it". The question asks "I create a branch with X, is there a faster way?". Your answer falls short on answering that. It's only explaining what the code in the question does, but it does not show a faster way.

Comment: @BDL Thanks for the constructive feedback - I've updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Meta-effect favoring you. I've seen many times when question is not received well, the self-answering even make it worse and unless the answer is good it gets downvoted too. How useful is the question? It might not have a duplicate, but isn't because it's the very very basic thing, the first few paragraphs of any git-documentation? I am not git-expert (luckily?) but if something is *usually* done in two steps and you make it one.. well.. cool? Save someone what?

Comment: @Sinatr The fact that the answer can be two steps or one is irrelevant. This meta question is about whether the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, IMO the question is a duplicate of this [Create a branch in Git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch). You're splitting hairs re the fast forward merge, as the answers are essentially the same. There's plenty of questions closed as dupes that are not 100% identical, but have the same answers.

The title of the linked potential dupe target *could* be regarded as misleading, wanting to prevent automatic fast forward, but the solutions still cover both use cases.

Believe it or not having the duplicates is not a bad thing, it helps people land on the with search engine results. You can't force people to agree or not agree with you on the duplicate, just as some people will not agree with me saying it is. Either way don't lose sleep over it.

Answer (score 5):

First of all your question title does not match with the answer you posted.

You asked

**"Create new branch to begin work on a new feature"**

But then your answer was

**You need to use `git checkout -b FEATURE` because it is a shortcut for the two commands `git branch FEATURE` and `git checkout FEATURE`**

The question title you should have used is

**"How do you create a branch and switch to it in a single command in git?"**

This is a title that matches what your answer says.

But your branching question is of course answered elsewhere in many other git questions - most of those questions have your answer as just a small part of the overall answer, but it is there, so it is a duplicate.

This question + answer pair for example is a perfect duplicate for yours:

Q: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/325727)

A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/816614/325727

Note that the answer to this question I have linked answers your question perfectly.  The other 2 questions that are linked as possible duplicates both contain an answer that says `git checkout -b FEATURE`, so they are also pretty close.

Conclusion: your question is 100% a duplicate, there is no doubt about this.  The wrong duplicate target may be linked, but this does not mean your question is not a duplicate.

Also btw, your question title "Create new branch to begin work on a new feature" is not even a question.  It should really have been "How do you create ... ?"

Comment: Regarding the question you indicate: `[...] it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.` 

The *answer* you mention may be a duplicate of my question, but the question itself isn't.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on the wording of the question title. I see many SO questions titles that aren't questions in the grammatical sense.  I searched meta and couldn't find anything on this. Do you have a link to a discussion on this?

Comment: I disagree with your assertion: `The question title you should have used is
"How do you create a branch and switch to it in a single command in git?"` The question is just about how to create a branch and begin work. You've added the requirement of doing it in a single command. My answer shows two solutions which both address the question as asked. Regardless, this meta question is about the question, not the answer :)

Comment: I also think [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch) is a perfectly fine dupe target, as that is basically what Tom is doing.

Comment: @Cerbrus I differentiated from that *question* in my original question. One of the answers may be the same, but the question is decidedly not. 

Your dupe target is about: `how you branch off from *another* branch and push back to the remote repository for the feature branch` as well as: `the branch seems ff merged, and I don't understand why.` My question is simply about branching from the current branch.  If I could edit the title, I'd be happy to change it to: "Create new branch from current branch to work on a new feature"

Comment: @TomHale: Please don't copy-paste comments.

Comment: OP have no intention to disallow multiple command answers.

Comment: [This meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/388243) explicitly says that titles should not start with "How do I...". (cc @TomHale )

Comment: I agree that closing as canonical may be a good thing, but... it is quite confusing when the canonical is locked as "not on-topic".

Answer (score 3):

I think your argument that [Create a branch in git from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch) is not a dupe because you're asking about the *current* branch but the question asks about *another* branch isn't a good argument. Your "current" branch is "another" branch. Both questions could be "How to create a new branch in git?".

They are similar enough for it to be a duplicate.

---

I see the argument has changed to "that question is about ff merges". That question is **not** about ff merges. It is about branching. The OP noticed unexpected behavior and thought he was branching incorrectly. **There is no question about ff merges in the dupe target**

Comment: The words of the *question* you link to contains the *answer* to my question: (`$ git checkout -b myfeature dev`). But the main thrust of the question you link to is about ff merges and remotes: `I mean that the branch seems ff merged, and I don't understand why...` `
`Can you explain me please how you branch off from another branch and push back to the remote repository for the feature branch?`

It's not a useful question to send someone to when they are trying to work out how to simply branch. That question's answer may contain the answer to mine, but the question is about something else.

Comment: The main question is `[How to] Create a branch in git from another brach`. That is reiterated near the end of the body `... explain me please how you branch off from another branch`. There is no question about ff merges, just showing what ff merges have happened. The bit at the end about remotes doesn't disqualify it as a duplicate. I think you should revisit your opinion on the usefulness of the question, 600k views, 1500+ upvotes, almost 300 favorites, and a whopping 2 downvotes for the entire Q&A say it has been incredibly helpful titled as `Create a branch in git from another branch`

Comment: The answer from one question `git checkout -b newbranch` cannot be trivially ported to other (it depends on whether one consider adding the original branch name to the end "trivial", but people who have to look up that question are unlikely to consider it so)

Comment: @user202729 Where did I say that? I was replying to a comment that suggested the question is not a good dupe target because it is not useful for learning about branching in git, which is simply false.

Answer (score 2):

Agree that the selected duplicates are not very duplicative. These questions have `git checkout -b NEWBRANCH` in the answer, so I have voted to reopen and when it reopens I will vote to close as duplicate to one of these questions:

[Create Git branch with current changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899627/create-git-branch-with-current-changes)

[Forgot to create new branch. How to transfer changes to new branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44728962/forgot-to-create-new-branch-how-to-transfer-changes-to-new-branch)

[Create a new branch in Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639980/create-a-new-branch-in-gitlab)

Comment: While the 3 questions you list have my answer in their answers, they don't have my question in their questions. How then can these *questions* be duplicate questions?

Comment: @TomHale - questions are duplicates if they have the same answer. Always been that way.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how to create a new branch. [This dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470523/create-a-branch-in-git-from-another-branch) answers that question.

If that's not what you're asking, you should clarify that in the question, including the question's *title*.

Comment: While there is an *answer* in that question that answers my question, the question itself is not the same, as I already highlighted in my original question:  [Your dupe target] is about: `how you branch off from *another* branch and push back to the remote repository for the feature branch` as well as: `the branch seems ff merged, and I don't understand why.` My question is simply about branching from the current branch.  If I could edit the title, I'd be happy to change it to: "Create new branch from current branch to work on a new feature"

Comment: Tom, if 2 _similar_ questions have the same answer on Stack Overflow, then they're duplicates. They don't need to be ___exactly___ the same. What's stopping you from editing the title?

Comment: I tried twice and got the message `This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed`. In trying to screenshot this, I was able to successfully edit the title. I was subsequently able to reproduce the message: [(screenshot)](https://i.imgur.com/cfSP27k.png)

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer: I do not intend to offend anyone in this post. If you think the language is problematic consider suggesting improvement.)

I can't read other people's minds, but I can guess that they think something like the following:

- It's soooo trivial. Not useful. Downvote.
- I hate it.
- If it's so trivial, I guess there should be a duplicate somewhere.
- *searching* → *choose top search result* → *vote to close* → *believe that Google search is accurate enough*

The downvote makes sense (well anyone can downvote for any reason, and if it's really "useful to beginners" then eventually they will upvote it anyway).

But I don't think the duplicate target are good: Although they both contains the answer to this question (`git checkout -b <branch-name>`, with explanation what the command does), they're more broad, and contains other questions not directly relevant to this question. That will make future users confused. (I have to admit that I still can't understand what the ff-merge question is asking)

As said in [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372471): Every time a question is closed when it doesn't make perfect sense, it's harder for every user who finds the question in the future to get their answer.

---

What should be done instead? I don't know. Some possible options:

- Leave a comment that explains that although you know that it's trivial you think it would help future visitors, and there are no canonical, etc.
  This may help, but that's not the correct use of comments.
- I have no other idea.

---

Some existing meta posts allows the creation of trivial Q&A (example: [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334091/5267751), [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260744/5267751)). There is no reason it should be closed, except duplicate.

Comment: If somebody disagrees with my opinion consider writing another post (of course)

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. I'll delay marking it as accepted to allow for other points of view.

I intended to vote to reopen my question at the same time as posting this meta question so that more informed people would be voting on the reopen request. Frustratingly, my reopen seems to be timed out for 2 days.  If you think my question is worthy of a re-open vote, I'd appreciate it if you voted accordingly.

Comment: `[...] if it's really "useful to beginners" then eventually they will upvote it anyway`: I believe that Google deprecates questions with negative scores and the [duplicate] flag, so there would be a bootstrapping process on people finding the question to be able to upvote it (so that it rises in the google rankings so that more people can find it). The target audience for this question would be less likely to go direct to SO to search.

Comment: @TomHale I don't think so. [Test](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20performance%20of%20conditional%20and%20assignment), [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136397/does-google-special-case-for-stack-overflow/136414#136414).

Comment: @TomHale, I do a lot of Q&A posts and the question often initially collects a few downvotes in the beginning but then goes positive later.

Comment: I don't believe the quote regarding punishment is a good fit for the answer. We *want duplicates to be closed* and it is **not punishment** when done well.  Perpetuating the myth that duplicate closure is punishment just causes more people to feel bad when they as a duplicate instead of feeling relief that their question is answered.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Read: you make future readers find it harder to find the answer. // Changed accordingly. Is that ok?