# Why was this question under discussion on meta.SO deleted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

The duplicate status of the question:

[Create new branch to begin work on a new feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46706821/5353461)

is currently under discussion on meta.SO:

[Why is this question a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373487/5353461)

To my reading, the [top voted post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373497/5353461) seems to disagree with the duplicate flag.

The other two answers point out questions with *answers* which are duplicate answers, but the questions do not seem to be duplicate *questions*.

I believe that I took on all the feedback I received in the meta question.

I now see that the question has been deleted. `JK.` is one of the users who deleted the question. In [JK.'s answer to the duplicate status meta-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373561/5353461) he says:

> Conclusion: your question is 100% a duplicate, there is no doubt about this. The wrong duplicate target may be linked, but this does not mean your question is not a duplicate.
>
> Also btw, your question title "Create new branch to begin work on a new feature" is not even a question. It should really have been "How do you create ... ?"

Even if JK is right on his 100% assertion (the meta question votes disagree), why wasn't the question left as a duplicate?

Why was the original question deleted?

Comment: `Even if JK is right on his 100% assertion (the meta question votes disagree)` I see no evidence of the votes disagreeing. Perhaps you mean there is not as much agreement as with the top-voted answer, but that is not the same statement, especially when considering JK. received 4 votes in 8 hours while the top answer was posted over 2 days ago and only received a net 6 votes (including _5 downvotes_). I'd say the disagreement is with the top answer.

Comment: Just like other closed questions, duplicates get deleted if people think they're not useful. Posting on Meta about a post tends to pull opinions towards the extremes (as in you're more likely to have people take some action on the post, whether positive or negative).

Comment: Duplicates are based on having the same **answer** and not the same *question*. The site has always operated on that basis. `2+3` and `1+4` as well as `6-1` are all duplicate questions as they have the exact same **answer**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably because 75% of that question's content isn't the question itself. There is a *lot* of noise in the question.

All that noise is saying is: *"This is not a duplicate of that"*, without going into any detail why it's not, so it really doesn't add anything to the question.

Comment: Yes, the duplicates differentiation took up a lot of space. This question has a fair bit of meta associated with it. How else should I have done it? Each one in a comment? I'm genuinely curious, so I asked: [How to distinguish a question from its marked duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373584/5353461)

You said: `without going into any detail`. For **each** of the dupe targets I stated why I believe it is not a duplicate. Which of the differentiations I gave did you find unclear or needing more detail?

Comment: Out pof those 4 bullet points, only the first one provides some reasoning. The other ones are simply _"This is not about X"_. That's not good enough. The first bullet also doesn't justify re-opening. That first one is a generic answer that also applies to your specific case.

Comment: I've updated the question. For others reading through this, the question as referred to at the time of asking looked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46706821/9)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373580/3956566). That just stating it's not a duplicate with no reason would not be helping.

I also left a comment on the [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373583/3956566), that I wanted to include as an answer:

> The meta effect certainly draws people attention to posts. And more so, users who are active in moderating the site. So if a post grates in any way, as an OP nitpicking over a duplicate target (this is how it may be perceived) or the OP comes across in a negative way at all, IMO the post is more likely to be deleted. But it certainly doesn't mean that the post will be inevitably deleted. I'd preface that with "if it's off topic or a duplicate" it's more likely to be deleted. My ten cents.

So to add to the other answers:

Whether the question is ultimately closed as a duplicate or left open, it doesn't necessarily warrant deletion. Even as a duplicate it helps assist in search engine results for people looking for this issue. IMO people are too hasty in deleting duplicates. You did the right thing bringing it to meta.

Answer (score -13):

Because it only takes three 10k users to delete any closed question.

When a closed question is linked from meta, several high rep users are going to see it, so if it's not reopened quickly, it will inevitably be deleted, regardless of quality.

See also: [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect?s=1|147.7690)

Comment: Are you implying the meta effect only has negative consequences?

Comment: Positive or negative depends if you believe that everything should be ultimately deleted.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Are you implying that the meta effect only results in closure, downvoted or delete votes, regardless of quality?

Comment: Not always, sometimes things get salvaged too, what you mention is the most frequent outcome.

Comment: Hardly. However, when a question is brought up on meta, it's often because of an OP disagreeing with the closure. Often those questions _are_ bad, so it's not surprising they end up getting deleted.

Comment: Following question: Are you sure you want to imply that? 
We all know the truth question brought on meta are under the form "How bad it is?" or "Is it really bad". And no matter how "good" or "ok" they are,  if we are looking for something bad most of the time you will find some.

Comment: Downvoted question brought with the "help me get it better" mood often get sympaty upvote because no one deserve a -11 on a one liner question. When there are more downvotes that words in the question.

Comment: If we're talking specifically about duplicates, then I'd probably agree that it will get deleted regardless of quality (theoretically, at least). If we're talking about *any* closed question (and actually plenty of duplicates too), it's probably a bit misleading to say "regardless of quality", because many closures are due to low quality, so you're saying quality doesn't matter only *after* we've established quality is low enough for it to stay closed. It would kind of be like saying "You're going to get banned if you keep behaving badly, regardless of how you behave".

Comment: The meta effect certainly draws people attention to posts. And more so, users who are active in moderating the site. So if a post grates in any way, as an OP nitpicking over a duplicate target (this is how it may be perceived) or the OP comes across in a negative way at all, IMO the post is more likely to be deleted. But it certainly doesn't mean that the post will be inevitably deleted. I'd preface that with "if it's off topic or a duplicate" it's more likely to be deleted. My ten cents.