# How to distinguish a question from its marked duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions, specific-answer

If a question has marked duplicates, where is the best place to distinguish the question from its dupe targets?

- In the question itself
- In the comments

Or doesn't it matter?

I ask because [this meta answer on why a question was deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373580/5353461) seems to look negatively upon putting the distinguishing text in the question body.

Should putting duplicate differentiation in the question body be grounds for closing [the original (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46706821/5353461)?

Comment: The answer says _“All that noise is saying is: ‘This is not a duplicate of that’, **without going into any detail why it's not**”_. You should explain why your question is different in the question itself, but the most important thing is that you should _precisely explain why_, not just claim that it isn’t a duplicate.

Comment: [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)

Comment: @Xufox, for each of the 4 questions I believe I did explain precisely why they were different. Quoting from each: 1. `This question is simply about branching from the current branch.` 2. `this question is about creating a local not a remote branch` 3. `this question is not about remote tracking` 4.  `this question is not about merging or pushing`. What would you have done differently?

Comment: Meta users have effective ways to express the "oh, stick a sock into it already" notion.  Getting that question re-opened was the first sock.  If you just keep going on about it over and over again even though you got what you wanted then additional socks are applied.

Comment: And to add to what Hans explained: This is the 3rd question you posted now, about that question of yours... That's 2 too many.

Comment: @Hans The question only got repoened *after* I posted the other questions. I'm grateful to have learned a lot in the process, and the original question is much improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The body of a question is a good place to show what you're asking, and what you've tried. For example, you can share things like *I've tried the solution found here, but that resulted in <an error description>*.

In general, if you ask a clear, well-defined question, it should be obvious if it is or isn't a duplicate. Clarifying and specifying should be done in the question body.

Discussing incorrect flagging can either be done in the comments (even though they aren't intended for that), or on meta (like you've already done). You should never discuss flags or incorrect closure in the question body or title.

Referring to the dupe in the body, like *not a duplicate because of <reason>* is a bad practice as well, because it loses context if the question gets reopened.

---

To discuss some specifics:

> (Reopen reviewers: please read this question's meta discussion)

This is clearly not part of the question, so it shouldn't be there.

> Create a branch in Git from another branch is about: how you branch off from *another* branch and push back to the remote repository for the feature branch as well as: the branch seems ff merged, and I don't understand why. This question is simply about branching from the current branch.
>
> How do you create a remote Git branch? - this question is not about creating a local not a remote branch.

This is all not really relevant. I can't tell if the answers and explanations on those questions suffice for yours. I can only tell that you think they discuss different subjects, which is not relevant for your question.

> The following two questions were initially marked as duplicates, but then removed after my initial reopen request:
>
> Setting up remote tracking assuming a local branch has already been created - this question is not about remote tracking.
>
> Why an existing branch is ff merged and pushing it to a remote repository - this question is not about merging or pushing.

This is question history, which can be viewed in the timeline, and should not be included in the body as well.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful and detailed answer.

Answer (score 5):

> 75% of that question's content isn't the question itself. There is a *lot* of noise in the question.
>
> All that noise is saying is: *"This is not a duplicate of that"*, ***without going into any detail*** why it's not, so it really doesn't add anything to the question.
> ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373580/1835379))

If you needed clarification about my answer, you should've commented on my answer.

A massive portion of that question is just you *claiming* it's not a duplicate. That's noise.

Comment: I believe I finally got your point (I now know how to differentiate questions properly). I've re-done the question and believe it looks way better - thank you. If you have any further feedback, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Yea, that's a lot better now.